# ActiveRecord OR clause in scoped query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
statuses = %w(sick healthy hungry)

query = User.scoped(:joins => 'left outer join pets on pets.user_id = users.id', :conditions => { 'pets.id' => nil, 'users.job_status' => stati })
```

Given the code above, is it possible to add an OR clause to the `:conditions` to say something like

```
where (pets.id is NULL AND users.status IN ('sick', 'healthy', 'hungry')) OR (users.gender = 'male')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using the [MetaWhere](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) gem

```
statuses = %w(sick healthy hungry)

query = User.include(:pets).where(
  ('pets.id' => nil, 'users.job_status' => statuses) |
  ('users.gender' => 'male')
)
```

The `|` symbol is used for `OR` condition.

**PS** : The `include` directive uses `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so there is no need to hand code the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SQL condition instead of a Hash condition:

```
query = User.scoped(
    :joins => 'left outer join pets on pets.user_id = users.id',
    :conditions => [
        '(pets.id is null AND users.status IN (?)) OR (users.gender = ?)',
        statuses, 'male'
    ]
)
```

Or:

```
query = User.scoped(
    :joins => 'left outer join pets on pets.user_id = users.id',
    :conditions => [
        '(pets.id is null AND users.status IN (:statuses)) OR (users.gender = :gender)',
        { :status => statuses, :gender => 'male' }
    ]
)
```

The downside is that you have to avoid trying `pets.is = NULL` by hand.