# how to implement and, or clauses in sql queries? ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I tried looking around but could not find an answer on how to implement the combination of **AND**,  **|**(or). I am getting an error. The code is listed below:

```
allgames = GameInfo.Get.where(["list = ? AND (lang = ? OR lang = ?)", "yes", "en", @lang]).order(:order)
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
The specified query expression syntax is not valid.
```

please shed some light,

Regards,

Comment: You need a better reference manual if you think `|` is valid SQL.

Comment: got the reference from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535592/activerecord-or-clause-in-scoped-query) really. Normally in SQL, you would use `OR`

Comment: If you read that answer carefully you'll see that it is using the MetaWhere gem and that gem is no longer being updated.

Comment: For literal strings, not Ruby code, you'll need to use pure SQL. That example employs some magic that converts Ruby expressions to SQL, a technique that's fallen out of favor because often it doesn't produce the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe is not used in sql:

```
where("list = ? AND (lang = ? OR lang = ?)", "yes", 'en',@lang)
```

Comment: its the same error message as above, `@lang` holds `params[:lang]` from url

Comment: Could you copy the generated query? Or at least the whole line of code.

Comment: Replace the pipe (`|`) with an `OR`, as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: could you edit your answer you need to get rid of square brackets! and it works.